# Querying Two Tables & Using Record Data as Column Headers in Access?

Tags: ms-access

This site has been super helpful with this database i am creating for work, i have a lot of VB knowledge but little SQL.

i am creating a database of cisco IP phones which records the MACs, serials and to what site id they are assigned to.

My managers have now decided to change the goal posts of my application once again and are now asking for me to create a form that displays data in a way i have no idea how to do.

what they now want and what i am hoping to achieve somehow is to create a sql statement that gets the count of the number handsets by site id and then to compare that number against the data from another table.

Here is the fields that we need to work with:

```
TABLE 1
Handset_Type
Handset_Site_Id

TABLE 2
Handset_Type
Handset_Site_Id
```

This is how i would like to display the data

```
SITE ID        | Handset_Type1      | Handset_Type1 
Handset_Site_id1 |COUNT TYPE1 FROM T1|COUNT TYPE1 FROM T2 
Handset_Site_id2 |COUNT TYPE1 FROM T1|COUNT TYPE1 FROM T2
```

If we can use the data in the Handset_type field to create the column headings then that would be great as there are only a few models of phones but if they are static columns then that will be ok also.

I hope i have explained this ok as i can see this may be complex to understand.

if you have any suggestions please let me know

Thank you

Steve

Comment: This sounds like a good fit for a crosstab query: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-HA010229577.aspx

Comment: Fairly easy to do with a combination union and crosstab query. Please clarify, do you want a separate column for each Handset_Type and source table? Please revise your question and show where 'Handset_Type2' would go. Also, just a data question: why do you have similar records stored in two different tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you would like to present the count of records from both tables, with the handset type and source table as column headings, for each site ID.

The first step is to merge your tables into a single table, creating a column which expresses the handset type and source table:

```
SELECT Handset_Type & " in T1" as TypeFromT, Handset_Site_Id FROM [Table 1]
UNION ALL
SELECT Handset_Type & " in T2" as TypeFromT, Handset_Site_Id FROM [Table 2]
```

This will form an inner query for the crosstab. The syntax for crosstabs can be a bit tricky so I usually build mine in design view. We define the `TypeFromT` as our new column heading and we use `Handset_Site_Id` both as our row groupings and as our counting field:

```
TRANSFORM Count(SubQry.Handset_Site_Id) AS SiteIDCount
SELECT SubQry.Handset_Site_Id
FROM (
    SELECT Handset_Type & " in T1" as TypeFromT, Handset_Site_Id FROM [Table 1]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Handset_Type & " in T2" as TypeFromT, Handset_Site_Id FROM [Table 2]
) AS SubQry
GROUP BY SubQry.Handset_Site_Id
PIVOT SubQry.TypeFromT;
```

The only catch is that if there are zero entries for the particular Handset Type, Source Table, and Site ID, the resulting value will be null instead of a 0. If that is undesirable, replace `Count(SubQry.Handset_Site_Id)` with `Nz(Count(SubQry.Handset_Site_Id),0)`

Comment: This is perfect, that is exactly what I was after. Thank you so much.
I wish i knew sql as well as you!

Comment: Hi would you have any idea if you can add another column to this query that displays the delta between the two tables?